# Find $P(3)+8P\left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If the polynomial $$P(x)=x^{3}+Ax^{2}+Bx+C$$

such that $P(1)=2 , P(2)=4$

Find $$P(3)+8P\left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )$$

A beautiful question, It's just for sharing a new ideas, thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

You have $A+B+C=1$ and $4A+2B+C=-4$

Then $3P+8P(\frac 32)=54+27A+15B+9C=54+3[2(4A+2B+C)+(A+B+C)]=33$

Comment: Nice solution (+1)

Answer (score 3):

We have:

> $P(1)=2$, then $A+B+C =1$.
>
> $P(2)=4$, then $4A+2B+C = -4$.

Therefore,

> $9A + 5B + 3C = -7$

Moreover,

> $P(3) + 8P(\frac{3}{2}) = 54 + 3(9A+5B+3C) = 54 - 21 = 33$

Comment: great solution (+1)